# error occurred when hokuyo node is launched

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I downloaded the hokuyo node, made it. When I tried to use the "hokuyo_test.launch" file given in the package to launch the hokuyo node, an exception threw out:

```
[ WARN] [1356005675.931956581]: The use_rep_117 parameter has not been specified and has been automatically set to true.  This parameter will be removed in Hydromedusa.  Please see: http://ros.org/wiki/rep_117/migration
[ERROR] [1356005680.166530146]: Exception thrown while opening Hokuyo.timeout reached (in hokuyo::laser::laserReadline) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting
```

I read the troubleshooting page, but there wasn't any description about "timeout".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50858/error-occurred-when-hokuyo-node-is-launched/) by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2012-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on 2012-12-20**:
I m actually using a serial usb converter cable, and i set the param “port” as "/dev/ttyUSB0", but i still get the timeout error

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-20**:
Are you running a URG via the serial connection? Why not just use USB directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like your port isn't set up properly.

I suggest plugging in your LiDAR to a USB port & running the following command to give get rw permissions:

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

---

Originally posted by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) with karma: 341 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1